Trace theorem for $L^2([0,1]; H^k(S^2))$
Consider a function $u$ in $L^2([0,1]; H^k(S^2))$ where $k$ is a positive integer.
Where would $u(0)$ live (or $u(r)$ for some fixed $r \in [0,1]$)? Is there a version of the trace theorem saying that $u(0) \in H^{k-1/2}(S^2)$? Or does it hold that $u(0) \in H^{k}(S^2)$?
What if we in addition know that $u' \in L^2[0,1]; H^{k'}(S^2))$ for some $k'\leq k$?
If you know any references that study the trace theorem for such spaces, please send them over.

For the question in your title: the constant function $1$ on $S^2$ is in any $H^k$. So any $L^2$ function $u$ can be realized as an $L^2([0,1]; H^k(S^2))$ function. But there is no "trace theorem" allow you to take pointwise values of an arbitrary $L^2$ function. // For the motivation: when $F \equiv 0$, your ODE is equivalent to $(e^r u(r))' = 0$. It is absolutely false that for arbitrary $u_0, u_1$ you can find a solution. Any solution must satisfy $u_0 = e \cdot u_1$. // Considering that you are studying a first order ODE, it doesn't make sense to give two boundary values.

Oh I didn't mean to add the "$u_1$". Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the post.
I see, so we cannot make sense of $u(r)$ for a given $r$. If we in addition know that $\partial_r u \in L^2([0,1];H^{k-1})$, then is there a trace theorem saying something about $u(0)$?

Yes there is, by interpolation theory, see e.g. here. This will give you $u(\tau) \in H^\ell(S^2)$ with $\ell = \frac12 k + \frac12 k'$ for every $\tau \in [0,1]$ with a uniform-in-$\tau$ norm dependence against $|u|{L^2(H^k)} + |u'|{L^2(H^{k'})}$.

@Hannes Thank you! That was what I was looking for. I guess "trace theorem" is not the right phrase to use.

@Laithy Actually, I would say "trace theorem" is just fine and in fact regularly used. :-)
